# MySQL : Optimizing simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Needless to say i am not proficient at SQL. Now i have to run a query on a table that looks like this :

```
 id, tp_id, value_1, value_2, value_3, date
```

This table has 2 entries for each distinct tp_id, with different values. tp_id is a foreign key, which is indexed, in the following table :

```
 id, external_id
```

I'm trying to retrieve data as follows :

Get distinct tp_id where value_2 = 2, value_1 = 1 | 2, value_3 = 1, and date < now - 1 year. These conditions must hold true for BOTH entries with matching tp_id

I have tried the following query, but as i understand it the SUM function paired with the JOIN statement makes the query too slow :

```
SELECT t1.tp_id, t2.external_id
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.tp_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.tp_id
HAVING 
  SUM(
    t1.value_2 = 2 
    AND t1.value_1 IN (1, 2) 
    AND t1.value_3 = 1 
    AND t1.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  ) = 2;
```

Both tables have roughly 2.5M rows.

I'd like to optimize this query or learn a better way to do this, so any help would be welcome.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: It appears running this query will be altogether unnecessary. I will therefore close the question, thanks for the answers

Comment: Why are you joining in this query? Are there multiple rows in t2 per t1 or could you just use t1?

Comment: Also, it's a little unclear to me, is there an index on `table_1.tp_id` _and_ on `table_2.external_id`?

Comment: Yes, there is an index on both columns. I made a mistake in the query i posted, i am joining because t1.tp_id = t2.id NOT t2.external_id. Editing query to reflect this

Comment: There's a requirement that is not written but that maybe is understandable from the query you wrote. 
Do you need to return the ID only if both 2 rows match the condition that you wrote, isn't it?

Comment: Given the update to the query, can you confirm that there is also an index on `table_2.id`?

Comment: Can you also post the explain plan?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: To answer both questions, yes there is an index on table_2.id, and yes both rows need to match the provided condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your requirement correctly, something like this might help.

```
SELECT tp_id
FROM (
    SELECT t1.tp_id,count(*) as count
    FROM table_1 t1
    WHERE
      t1.value_2 = 2 
      AND (t1.value_1 = 1 OR t1.value_1 = 2) 
      AND t1.value_3 = 1 
      AND t1.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    GROUP BY tp_id
) as res 
WHERE res.count = 2
```

Essentially, I did 3 performance update:

1. the WHERE condition is applied before the GROUP BY, way more performant than the HAVING
2. I've used a nested query, but you can also use HAVING COUNT(tp_id) = 2 depending on your MySQL version
3. 2 boolean checks should be more performant than an IN clause

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. I'm in transportation right now but will try this out as soon as i return.

Comment: Regarding the second query, wouldnt this return tp_ids for which one of the rows matched the conditions, but not the other ?

Comment: Pretty great, the explanation is awesome. I suspected that for the IN clause. I will give an update as i return to my pc. Thanks

Comment: I've just tried the query, unfortunately it also times out at ~30s. I'm curious as to what causes this, do you think it might be an issue with the underlying configuration/resources ?

Comment: Can you share your db model? So that we can check the primary keys? 2.5M rows are really a lot. Have you considered to prepare the results of your query in another table? Or in another way?

Comment: You can use, for example, materialised views together with events. Take a look at here: https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-materialized-views/